# I want to add orginal price, price, discount amount on order email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, order-email

I want to add 3 more columns on order email template (Table section). I found the good solution to add column into table:

http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/add-unit-price-to-order-email-template/

however, I don't know how can I get these values from order

- Original item price
- Item price
- Discount amount

I'd be grateful for any guidance.

Thanks,

Ryo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These depend on the type of discount. If they are catalog based (temporary price on the product or a catalog rule under promotions), then look in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`. All magic setters and getters are documented now.

So in your case:

- getOriginalPrice()
- getPrice()
- getDiscountAmount

Each of these have a "Base" version. That is the version in the store currency. If you provide the option to sell in other currencies, then base and normal version will differ.